# Perform Multiple Posts WIth Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel.foreach

Here is my syntax, but I keep have a compile error of on my line `Parallel.ForEach()`

> System.Data.DataRow is a type but is used like a variable

which I am sure is something simple that I am just overlooking.  Below is my full syntax, if someone could assist me with what exactly I am missing, I will greatly appreciate it!

```
private void TryParallel()
{
  Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  string strEndpointURL = string.Format("http://sitetosenddatato.com/post");
  SqlDataReader reader;
  string strPostData = "";
  string strMessage = "";
  DataSet grds = new DataSet();
  grds = GetSQLResults();
  if (grds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 1)
  {
    Parallel.ForEach(DataRow, grds.Tables[0].Rows =>
    {
        dic.Add("userID", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
        dic.Add("name", reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
        dic.Add("address", reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
        dic.Add("city", reader.GetValue(3).ToString());
        dic.Add("state", reader.GetValue(4).ToString());
        dic.Add("zip", reader.GetValue(5).ToString());
        dic.Add("Phone", reader.GetValue(6).ToString());
    });
  }
  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
  foreach (var d in dic) { strPostData += d.Key + "=" + Server.UrlEncode(d.Value) + "&"; }
  strPostData += "hs_context=";
S  ystem.Net.HttpWebRequest r = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strEndpointURL);
  r.Method = "POST";
  r.Accept = "application/json";
  r.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  r.ContentLength = strPostData.Length;
  r.KeepAlive = false;
  using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(r.GetRequestStream()))
  {
    try { sw.Write(strPostData); }
    catch (Exception ex) { strMessage = ex.Message; }
  }
  var response = r.GetResponse();
  Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
  var result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
  var xml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(result);
  if (xml.Elements("success").FirstOrDefault().Value == "1") { strMessage = "Success"; }
  else
  {
    var errors = xml.Elements("errors");
    foreach (var error in errors.Elements("error")) { strMessage = error.Value; }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

 Following the example outlined below by @Glen Thomas - I altered my code to

```
if (grds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
{
  Parallel.ForEach(rows, row =>
  {
    dic.Add("userID", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    //More Here
  }
}
```

which presents a compile error of:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'reader'

But I have `reader` declared at the top of my method?

Comment: @CodingGorilla the bulk of the code below the Parallel.ForEach needs to be in it to achieve what he is actually after, I suspect.

Comment: RE: undefined reader - you have it declared, but not instantiated.  The compiler sees that you never assign anything to it and refuses to compile.  This is just a safety mechanism as at runtime you would receive a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: again, the answer is in the exception - the compiler won't accept the use of reader unless you assign something to it.

Comment: The error messages aren't there for fun, they're trying to help you. Look at your code - " SqlDataReader reader;"   - this is still not assigned. The compiler told you what's wrong - you don't need to ask the internet :)

Comment: Basically, there are too many problems with this code to solve in just *one* question

Comment: @HenryC - oh you wise guru!  I have my code compiling and testing and you are correct, multiple additional errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifying a type name as the first parameter. This should be the collection you are iterating. The second parameter is a function to perform, with a parameter for each element in the collection.

The correct usage of Parallel.ForEach is like this:

```
var rows = new DataRow[0]

Parallel.ForEach(rows, row =>
{
    // Do something with row here
});
```

For your code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(grds.Tables[0].Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), row =>
{
    dic.Add("userID", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    dic.Add("name", reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
    dic.Add("address", reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
    dic.Add("city", reader.GetValue(3).ToString());
    dic.Add("state", reader.GetValue(4).ToString());
    dic.Add("zip", reader.GetValue(5).ToString());
    dic.Add("Phone", reader.GetValue(6).ToString());
});
```

Comment: You might consider updating your answer to include the OP's original code.

Comment: @Glen Thomas - see my edit.  I used your syntax which removed my initial error, but presents a new one...

Comment: I see many unrelated errors with your code. I guess there are many questions you will need to ask...

Comment: @GlenThomas - ah I did not know there were others.  I was building from ground up and fixing what the compiler would point out.

Comment: @MichaelMormon you probably need to go back to basics and have a think what you're trying to do in parallel asynchronously. are you wanting to make only one http POST, also? because your question suggests that you are trying to perform multiple POSTs.

Comment: would recommend that you plan (in pseudocode) what you are trying to do, and then write the code to implement that: eg 

- retrieve data from database, then 
- construct dictionary, then
- perform multiple posts in parallel

Comment: @HenryC - I am wanting to query the database, return the results (could be 1 or could be 50), then post 1 after another.

Comment: Does the order of the results matter to you? Because when you run in parallel this is no longer guaranteed.

Comment: Also, even if you manage to get that parallel working, your code will probably stop working as you're gonna have duplicate keys in your dictionary...etc.

Comment: @HenryC - no the order that the Post is performed in does not matter.  Any order will suffice.  Ah, I hadn't hit the duplicate key in dictionary yet...would have seen it once all compile errors were removed and I tested...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to do this instead:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(grds.Tables[0].Rows.OfType<DataRow>(), (row) =>
    {
        dic.Add("userID", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
        dic.Add("name", reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
        dic.Add("address", reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
        dic.Add("city", reader.GetValue(3).ToString());
        dic.Add("state", reader.GetValue(4).ToString());
        dic.Add("zip", reader.GetValue(5).ToString());
        dic.Add("Phone", reader.GetValue(6).ToString());

        //though realistically you should be doing something with your specific row
    });
```

The answer is in the error message you recieved - **DataRow is not defined as an object in the code you provided**.

However, this isn't even actually solving your actual problem which I believe is performing multiple HTTP posts in parallel - so you'd need to put your post logic within the anonymous function of your Parallel.ForEach()

Comment: I don't think this will compile. The second parameter of ForEach must take a delegate with a parameter.

Comment: @GlenThomas Good catch. For the uninitiated, here's an article on a simple Parallel.ForEach() -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx  To be fair there's plenty of other issues with the OP's code, too.